# Защита на файл

Tags: безопасность, jsp

Меня интересует, как защитить файл доступа к админке вот таким образом

```
$login="Логин";
$password="пароль в MD5";
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']!==$login || md5($_SERVER 
['PHP_AUTH_PW'])!==$password) {
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Protection of the admin panel"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
exit("Пошел вон от сюда !");}
```

Как сделать такую защиту на dlе, я знаю, а вот админка на сервере, а точнее iweb написан на jsp и он очень прост во взломе. Я бы хотел тоже защитить страничку авторизации таким образом. Как это сделать? 
Выглядит страница авторизации вот так:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%  boolean showTag = false;
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("username")!=null) showTag = true;

    boolean Proc = false;
    if (request.getParameter("password")!=null) Proc = true;
    if (showTag) Proc = false;

if(Proc)
{
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String loginrecord = null;
    int separatorIndex = 0;
    String recordUsername = null;
    String recordPassword = null;
    int recordLength = 0;
    boolean matchTag = false;

    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/opt/jakarta-tomcat-5.5.9/webapps/iweb/loginlist.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        loginrecord = new String();
        while((loginrecord=br.readLine())!=null && !matchTag){
            recordLength = loginrecord.length();
            separatorIndex = loginrecord.indexOf(":");
            recordUsername = loginrecord.substring(0, separatorIndex);
            recordPassword = loginrecord.substring(separatorIndex+1,recordLength);
            if(recordUsername.compareTo(username)==0){
                if((recordPassword.compareTo(password)==0)) matchTag = true;
            } 
        }
        if(matchTag){
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/opt/jakarta-tomcat-5.5.9/webapps/iweb/login.log",true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            Date dateToday = new Date();
            String logStr = recordUsername+":login:"+dateToday;
            bw.write(logStr);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
            bw = null;
            fw = null;
        }
        fr = null;
        br = null;

    }catch(Exception e){
        out.println("Error!"+e.getMessage());
    }

    if(matchTag){
        request.getSession().setAttribute("username", username);
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("loginform.jsp?err=1");
    }

}
else
{
%>
<html>
<head>
<%@include file="include/head.jsp"%>
</head>
<body>
<table width="96%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr align="center"><td><img src="/iweb/images/pw-header.jpg"></img></td></tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<%
if(showTag)
{%>
    <tr><td colspan="2" class="ver_12_black_b">&nbsp;&nbsp;Вы уже авторизованны!</td></tr> 
    <%

} else {

    String strErr = "";
    if(request.getParameter("err")!=null && request.getParameter("err").equals("1")) strErr = "Неверно!!";%>
    <tr><td colspan="2" class="ver_12_black_b">&nbsp;&nbsp;Напишитн что хз:</td></tr> 
    <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="5%"></td>
        <td width="95%">
        <form name="login" action="loginform.jsp">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                <%  if(!strErr.equals("")){ %>
                    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td colspan="2" class="ver_10_red"><%=strErr%></td></tr><%}%>     
                <tr><td width="10%" class="ver_10_black">Пользователь:</td>
                    <td width="90%"><input type="text" name="username" value=""></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td width="10%" class="ver_10_black">Пользователь2:</td>
                    <td width="90%"><input type="text" name="password" value=""></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td class="ver_10_black">Пароль:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="username" value=""></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Вход" class="button">
                        <input type="reset" value="Отмена" class="button">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>   
    <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr><%
}%> 
</table>

</body>
</html><%
}%>
```

Comment: Это тихий позорный ужас. Выкиньте это немедленно, пока не спалились :))

Comment: вы по поводу чего ужас говорите? По поводу кода?(я его не писал)  Или метода защиты?)

Answer (score 1):

Если честно, то это написано коряво. Нельзя СТОЛЬКО логики пихать в jsp, вынесите ее в отдельный класс java.

Answer (score -1):

Ну так и в чём проблема? В Java точно так же проверяете параметры и выставляется хидеры респонза (с помощью [addHeader](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)) или шлёте лесом в случае чего.

Comment: я просто в яве мягко говоря нуб. Может есть у кого готовый код?

Comment: Нет.. никакой готовый код тут не поможет. Эту страницу надо сначала разбить на части и выкинуть из неё всё это безумие..